# How to maintain a patched upstream package

Tags: packaging, patch, git-buildpackage

I'm looking for the best way to maintain a patched version of an upstream ubuntu package. Here's the situation:

We have our own server running reprepro, which would host the modified package. Our other packages are managed using git and the git packaging tools (git-dch, git-buildpackage).

I have the .diff file that contains the patch to the upstream source, which I've applied before by doing `apt-get source pkgname`, applying it and running debuild. I'd like to track it properly this time using git.

What's the best process for managing this?

Comment: You'd probably get more answers somewhere else... maybe http://stackoverflow.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something a little different than Flimzy. Take a look at `git-import-dsc` and possibly `git-debimport`. They will auto-magically create separate upstream, debian, and prinstine-tar branches from at Debian source package. You could then create your own branch for your patch set. Each time a new upload to Ubuntu is made, you can just run `git-import-dsc` on the new package and merge with your branch.

Even simpler would be to use `bzr` if you are not wed to `git`. Each Ubuntu package can also be found in a `bzr` branch. `bzr branch ubuntu:$PACKAGE_NAME` will grab the source branch for you.  Make your changes and commit. Then when ever a new Ubuntu upload is made, you can simply run `bzr merge-package ubuntu:$PACKAGE_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm understanding your question fully...

Here's how I do it:

1. Place the *.orig.tar.gz *.diff.gz and *.dsc files in a directory aptly named for your package
2. Unpack the source (dpkg-source -x *.dsc).  You'll now have three files and one sub-directory
3. Commit this to your RCS (commit A)
4. Apply your changes, and commit to your RCS (Commit B)
5. Make any future changes, and commit (Commit N)

When a new upstream version comes out:

1. Create a diff between Commit A and Commit N
2. Repeat steps 1-3 above
3. Apply your diff (created in step 1), and commit (new Commit A)
4. Make any future changes and commit (Commit N)

Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Hm, that seems reasonable. I'll give that a try.